# Facebook Open Graph weird descriptions

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Im having this weird issue, where the description I'm posting is not the same as the post in Facebook. Im using the functions provided by the Facebook sdk(3.14.1).

Im using this function to upload a image, which i will get the id of the image.

```
+ (FBRequestConnection *)startForUploadStagingResourceWithImage:(UIImage *)image
                                          completionHandler:(FBRequestHandler)handler;
```

Using the image id, i create the open graph objects using this function.

```
+ (FBRequestConnection *)startForPostWithGraphPath:(NSString *)graphPath
                                   graphObject:(id<FBGraphObject>)graphObject
                             completionHandler:(FBRequestHandler)handler;
```

With object id, i attempt to post the open graph objects using this function with the action id.

```
+ (FBRequestConnection *)startForPostOpenGraphObjectWithType:(NSString *)type
                                                   title:(NSString *)title
                                                   image:(id)image
                                                     url:(id)url
                                             description:(NSString *)description
                                        objectProperties:(NSDictionary *)objectProperties
                                       completionHandler:(FBRequestHandler)handler;
```

The parameters can be seen in the screenshot provide below:

[image: The object graph object post]
[image: The object graph object in debugger]
[image: The object graph action in debugger]

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in the open graph stories. There is a edit attachment button, there are items in the caption that overwrites all the dynamic data i set in the object.

Once i removed the items, the text that was set into each object was displayed accordingly.